# Objective C some NSString dont turn to NSCFString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

Hi I have a problem I have declared and initialized 3 variables NSString

```
static NSString* accidtest;
static NSString* accnumber;  
static NSString* accprefix;
```

later in program

```
[[accidtest initWithString:@"0293749372920383"]freeWhenDone:NO]; 
[[accnumber alloc] init];
[[accprefix alloc] init];
```

And I gave them a value from xml
like that

```
accnumber = string;
accprefix = string;
```

but in the end when i want to use them I found the problem that only accnumber turn into NSCFString and save his value other are out of scope.

thank for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is more correct:

```
/* these initialize to nil */
static NSString* accidtest;
static NSString* accnumber;
static NSString* accprefix;

/* ... */

/* ??? freeWhenDone */
assert(nil == accidtest); /* make sure we aren't creating twice, leaking the previous assignment */
accidtest = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0293749372920383"];

assert(nil == accnumber); /* make sure we aren't creating twice, leaking the previous assignment */
accnumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];

assert(nil == accprefix); /* make sure we aren't creating twice, leaking the previous assignment */
accprefix = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `-alloc` on a non-initialized variable. This doesn't make any sense, and the compiler should be yelling at you for it. Instead you should have something like

```
accidtest = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"0293749372920383"];
accnumber = [[NSString alloc] init]; // what's the point of this? Equivalent to @""
```